# Javascript variable is changing its value, reasons that can cause such?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am debugging the weirdest error I ever seen. At this point my code look like this.

```
        var counter = 0;
function setup() {
    var count = ++counter;
    var test = false;

    function getSetter(arg?) {
        if (typeof (arg) !== "undefined") {
            console.log(["setting",count, arg]);
            test = arg;
        } else {
            console.log(["getting",count, test]);
            return test;
        }

    }
    return getSetter;
}
var verticalScrollDisabled = setup();
```

<strike>this is in a closed scope and i have made sure that the variable test is not accessed outside the above code. I can change it to any name with same result.</strike> Updated such its clear that its not accessed outside of this scope. And updated with a counter to show its not written over.

Copy pasting result from the console.

```
 ["enter scroll area", div.fxs-blade-content, true, "3511>401 || 577>585"]    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:12 
 ["setting", 1,true]    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:132 
 disable vert    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:72 
 n.Event {originalEvent: WheelEvent, type: "mousewheel", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1422128039040, jQuery21104183536011260003: true…}    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:15 
 ["getting", 1,false]    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:15 
 ["getting", 1, false]    HorizontalScrollBindingHandler.ts:75 
 [false, false]
```

#### Issue

As commented, my problem is that as seen in the trace. the variable get set to true, but when its being accessed again its false. I cant get why that can happen.

and the handler attached to mousescroll event.

```
var scrollHorizontally =(e) => {

         //   console.log([verticalScrollDisabled(), scrollInAction]);
            console.log(e);
            if (verticalScrollDisabled() && !scrollInAction)
                return;
            console.log([verticalScrollDisabled(), scrollInAction]);
```

<strike>This code has been working for ever and nothing changed to it other than we in some seperate code are opening a popup and closing it again. Is there anything that could cause events to be doing something out of the expected related to if the window loses focus or something? Again, the test variable is not altered outside the verticalcrollDisabled function, so I have no clue why it can go change itself to false, notice the ["setting", true].</strike>

Just verified that the popup is not the cause.

Heres the hole file. https://gist.github.com/s093294/e49ed46d2680c1403e3b

Comment: Please don't require us to decipher your code to figure out what it's supposed to do. You need to clearly _explain_ what your code is supposed to do, what is the expected result, and how that differs from the actual result. You've provided us a trace output with no context whatsoever.

Comment: This is how I see this code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2smoze5k/1/). In separate file VerticalScroll.js.

Comment: @JLRishe, the variable is set to true, but when accessed it is returned as false. Maybe that was not clear.

Comment: @pksorensen Thank you for explaining that. So maybe `verticalScrollDisabled` is getting overwritten with a new `setup()` at some point and going back to its initial value? I don't see anything in the code you've given that would cause this issue, so the problem is almost surely somewhere else. Try adding a `console.log()` line inside the `setup()` function and outside the inner function. That will let you know every time `setup()` is called.

Comment: I added the hole file with the code. I simply cannot figure out what can cause this. Its part of a larger project and its been working fine. Need to backtrace what changed.

Comment: Added an alert in setup and you was right. it was called 2 times. Now i need to figure out how the module loader did that :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, validate your assumptions.

I assumed that the file was not loaded twice since it being a module defined with define and loaded with requirejs. This didnt hold up since there was some ID mapping that made two ids load this file and as one of the comments said, this is the thing that makes it possible.

I resolved the requirejs configuration and problem vent away.